# Lifecycle hook for child component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, childrelationship, parent-to-child, lifecycle

I understand lifecycle hooks for a custom LWC. But how do I detect when a child LWC has loaded in the DOM? For example, let's say I have a `<lightning-datatable>` that is a child of a custom LWC I'm developing. What's the best way to detect when that datatable has loaded in the DOM?

Comment: This may be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to accomplish? Where are you stuck? How can we help?